# Prehomogeneous varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

A prehomogeneous *vector space* is a pair $(G,V)$ where $V$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-vector space of dimension $n$ and $G$ is a reductive group of complex dimension $n$, such that $G$ admits a group action on $V$. If we embed $G$ into $\text{GL}(V)$, then the subgroup $G^\circ$ whose image in $\text{GL}(V)$ has absolute determinant one acts on $V$ with a single open orbit. In this case the ring of polynomial invariants is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[x]$, and is generated by a polynomial which can be called the *discriminant*. The open orbit is given by the non-vanishing of the discriminant.

An example of a prehomogeneous vector space is given by $G = \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ and $V = \{a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 y + a_1 xy^2 + a_0 y^3 : a_i \in \mathbb{C}\}$ the space of binary cubic forms, with the group action given by substitution.

I am interested in the following generalization: let $V$ instead be a projective *variety*, and $G$ a reductive group acting on $V$, and such that $\dim_{\mathbb{C}} G = \dim_{\mathbb{C}} V$. If $V$ is geometrically irreducible then there will only be one open orbit, defined by the non-vanishing of some polynomial which then generates the ring of polynomial invariants.

Have such pairs $(G,V)$ been studied in the literature (I think of them as ``prehomogeneous varieties" as in the title of the question, but perhaps they go by a different name)?

Examples include the spaces of *Klein forms* of degrees $3,4,6,12,20$. Klein forms are binary forms which admit an exceptionally large finite subgroup of $\text{PGL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ as an automorphism group. All binary cubic forms are Klein forms, giving the example of a prehomogeneous vector space above, while quartic Klein forms are defined by the vanishing of the $I$-invariant. That is, if we put

$$\displaystyle V_4 = \{a_4 x^4 + \cdots + a_0 y^4 : a_i \in \mathbb{C}\}$$

then the set of quartic Klein forms is given by the variety $\mathcal{V}_4 = \{a_4 x^4 + \cdots + a_0 y^4 : 12 a_4 a_0 - 3 a_3 a_1 + a_2^2 = 0\}$, which is a quadric 3-fold in $V_4$. Similarly, Klein forms of degrees 6, 12, and 20 are given by intersections of quadric hypersurfaces (see this paper by [Bennett and Dahmen](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2013/177-1/p04)). In each case there is only one open orbit under $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$. For example, all non-degenerate (i.e., with non-zero discriminant) quartic Klein forms are $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$-equivalent to the form $x(x^3 + y^3)$.

Comment: The assumption that $G$ should have dimension equal to $\dim(V)$ sounds unusual to me, and highly restrictive (for instance it excludes $\mathrm{SL}(V)$ acting on $V$ if $V\neq 0$). Also I'm confused by the assertion on invariants: if there is an open orbit, isn't the $\mathbf{C}$-algebra of invariants reduced to constants?

Comment: A class of examples are (projective) toric varieties

Comment: Look up "equivariant compactifications of homogeneous spaces".

Comment: @YCor I am not sure I understand your objection. Certainly prehomogeneous vector spaces are well-understood objects in the literature. There is nothing preventing you from say embedding $G$ into $\text{SL}(V)$ in your example, say

Comment: This is not my objection. My main objection is that if $G$ has an open orbit on $V$, then the algebra invariant is reduced to constants (instead of being isomorphic to $\mathbf{C}[x]$).

Comment: @YCor I believe restricting to the subgroup having absolute determinant one addresses your concern. See current version

Comment: You're now writing that there is an open $G$-orbit as a consequence, but it seems to be an assumption. Also, purely for the terminology, it seems to be that requiring that $G$ has dimension equal to $\dim(V)$ is not usual in "prehomogeneous vector space". (Still it's a reasonable assumption.)

Comment: AS @YCor [says](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376469/prehomogeneous-varieties#comment955219_376469), you start off with a mere group action (which I *think* means linear action *of* a group—it seems like a strange way of saying it), and claim that it has an open orbit.  This seems impossible to deduce merely as a consequence of the group action.  For example, $G$ might act trivially.

Comment: There _are_ a few general assumptions that assure an open orbit, or something close to it, e.g., via Baire category enhanced by the topological relations between the orbits.

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of toric varieties, there's also a very active field of spherical varieties $V$ on which a reductive group $G$ acts with an open dense orbit under a Borel subgroup $B$. They bear a resemblance to the theory of prehomegeneous vector spaces, but the lack of a vector space structure makes them much more difficult to study.